# Sum of complex exponential which gives cosine

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following expression: let be $\omega = \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n})$. I have to calculate

$$\omega^j+ \omega^{(n-1)j}$$ with $0\le j \le n-1$. I have to find a cosine from the expression above. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\omega^j + \omega^{(n-1)j} &= \exp(\frac{2\pi i j}{n}) + \exp(\frac{2\pi i (n-1)j}{n}) = \exp(\frac{2\pi i j}{n}) + \exp(-\frac{2\pi i j}{n} + 2\pi ij) \\
&= \exp(\frac{2\pi i j}{n}) + \exp(-\frac{2\pi i j}{n}) = 2 \cos(\frac{2 \pi j}{n})
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you Fenris, just a clarification: in the third equality you mean $ \exp (-\frac{2 \pi i j}{n}+ 2\pi i j) $, that is there is a $j$ that multiply $2\pi i $. Of course this not changes the result, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thank you. That one slipped by. That is corrected now.